# Find the relationship between a, b, c and d for a genenral cubic function

Tags: calculus, functions

For a cubic function
$$ = ^3 +^2 +  + $$
where a, b, c and d are constants, and the values of at least some of these constants determine the shape of the cubic. Find the relationship (a formula) between a, b, c and d when the graph has a **hump and a dip**? when the graph has **no humps or dips but one point with zero slope**? and when the graph has **no humps, dips or points with zero slope**?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: Suppose cubic as $f(x)$ and determine the nature of roots of $f'(x)$.